# Power BI DAX Measure Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I have to create the difference between the physical date and the created on date, using the the "received pricing" status in the workflow status.

I am needing to know how many days it took to get to that specific status("Received pricing" in the workflow status columns-which has multiple different status types).

so basically how many days between physical date to created date with the filter "received pricing" in the workflow status column.

Please advise.

Tried different measures, none worked

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so we can help you.